# onScanFailure after a certain of time when scanning ble devices in android

Tags: rxandroidble, rxbluetooth

I am using rxbleandroid library for scanning Bluetooth devices

```
fun startScan() {
    if(rxBleClient.isScanRuntimePermissionGranted) {
        Log.d("TAG", "All permission granted")
    }
    else {
        Log.d("TAG", "Not all permission granted\"")
    }
    val scanSettings = ScanSettings.Builder()
        .setScanMode(SCAN_MODE_BALANCED)
        .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
        .build()
    val scanFilter = ScanFilter.Builder()
        .build()
    rxBleClient.scanBleDevices(scanSettings, scanFilter)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doFinally { dispose() }
        .subscribe({scanResult ->
            Log.d("TAG", scanResult?.bleDevice?.name!!)


        },
            {
            onScanFailure(it) })

        .let {
            scanDisposable = it}//
}

private fun dispose() {
    //scanDisposable = null
}
private fun onScanFailure(throwable: Throwable) {
    Log.d("TAG", "onScanFailure ${throwable. Cause}")
    viewModelScope.launch{
        delay(6000)
        scanDisposable?.dispose()
        startScan()
    }
}
```

After a short while a get a onScanFailure event. The output on the screen is
`onScanFailure null`

The only way to fix it is to wait little bit and restart the scanning.
I am using the latest version of android on a pixel6. The version number of rxAndroidLibraryble is 1.17.0
Am i using the library wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the callback function you are using this line:

`Log.d("TAG", scanResult?.bleDevice?.name!!)`

It will throw an NPE once a device with no advertised name will get scanned and that NPE will have no cause.

You could use this:

`Log.d("TAG", scanResult?.bleDevice?.name ?: "no name")`

Comment: Is it an expected behavior. Should I restart the scanning after that?

Comment: NPE = NullPointerException is a very standard behaviour in Java, so yes — it is expected. You should avoid writing code that may throw in the first place. You can restart scanning after an NPE but it will happen again once the same device is scanned again due to how you have written the code.